# How to navigate from xib to other xib in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I want to navigate from xib that controlled by swift class to other xib that controlled by objective-c class.

Here is my code:

```
let cb_main_noticeView = cb_main_notice(nibName: "cb_main_notice", bundle: nil) as cb_main_notice
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(cb_main_noticeView, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

** It didn't work **

Note: cb_main_notice is controlled by objective-c class

Comment: So what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.presentViewController(cb_main_noticeView, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Juste remove the navigationController, if you don’t have a navigation controller in your app.